# npTDMS Python package not reading all channels of my desired .tdms file?

Tags: python, labview

I am setting up a data processing script for a short research paper and have trouble with the npTDMS package. I set up the plugin successfully in spyder and already read an example `.tdms` file I got.

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile 
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
data_folder = Path(r"C://Users/brue_sb/Studienarbeit/Beispieldaten/Test1-10/")
filename = data_folder / "S1.tdms"
tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(filename)
```

Labview records 5 channels of data only in the first group of the .tdms file. However my code can only call the first 4 channels. I have not yet been able to get the data from the 5th channel ("Untitled 4" instead of "Untitled 3") to be read.

```
for group in tdms_file.groups() :
    group_name = group.name
    
    for channel in group.channels():
        print(channel)
        channel_name = channel.name
        #print(channel_name)
        # Access dictionary of properties:
        properties = channel.properties
        # Access numpy array of data for channel:
        data = channel[:]

channel = tdms_file["Untitled"]["Untitled 3"]
```

I set up the script similar to the package documentation and also tried having ChatGPT write a simple script resulting in exactly same problem: the last channel is not taken into account. I have no idea what I am doing wrong or if it is the file or something else that is not according to specs. Getting the data from all the other channels `Untitled`, `Untitled 1`,... works but calling the 5th channel the same way by its title `Untitled 4` results in an error message saying:

```
  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py:407 in __getitem__
    return self._channels[channel_name]

KeyError: 'Untitled 4'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\brue_sb\.spyder-py3\tdms-auswertung.py:30
    channel = tdms_file["Untitled"]["Untitled 4"]

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py:409 in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(

KeyError: "There is no channel named 'Untitled 4' in group 'Untitled' of the TDMS file"
```

When opened in Excel the file clearly contains 5 channels, `Untitled 4` is just simply not being read:

[image: Excel view of the file]

[image: Second view of the data]

Somehow python does not recognize the fifth channel. When pasting the channel names in the `for`-loop getting all the channels in the group, `Untitled 4` is missing:

```
runfile('C:/Users/brue_sb/.spyder-py3/TDMS-auswertung.py', wdir='C:/Users/brue_sb/.spyder-py3')
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Untitled'>]
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled'>
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled 1'>
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled 2'>
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled 3'>
```

Unfortunately I do not have another file with multiple channels on hand yet. Other files with just a single channel work just fine, I have tried those already.

Edit: tdms file attached on this cloud folder https://cloud.tu-braunschweig.de/s/GQEBdMGF9Qo3R5o

Edit2: This is the code line that is causing

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
data_folder = Path(r"C://Users/brue_sb/Studienarbeit/Beispieldaten/Test1-10/")
filename = data_folder / "S1.tdms"
tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(filename)
groupcount = tdms_file.groups()
print(groupcount)
#data = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
#print(data)
for group in tdms_file.groups() :
    group_name = group.name
    
    for channel in group.channels():
        print(channel)
        channel_name = channel.name
        #print(channel_name)
        # Access dictionary of properties:
        properties = channel.properties
        # Access numpy array of data for channel:
        data = channel[:]

channel = tdms_file["Untitled"]["Untitled 4"]
```

Causing this outout:

```
runfile('C:/Users/brue_sb/.spyder-py3/TDMS-auswertung.py', wdir='C:/Users/brue_sb/.spyder-py3')
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Untitled'>]
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled'>
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled 1'>
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled 2'>
<TdmsChannel with path /'Untitled'/'Untitled 3'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py:407 in __getitem__
    return self._channels[channel_name]

KeyError: 'Untitled 4'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\brue_sb\.spyder-py3\tdms-auswertung.py:30
    channel = tdms_file["Untitled"]["Untitled 4"]

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\nptdms\tdms.py:409 in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(

KeyError: "There is no channel named 'Untitled 4' in group 'Untitled' of the TDMS file"
```

The first 4 channels are successfully read by the for loop, the 5th one isn't though. When calling the 5th channel explicitly again in the last row python cannot find a 5th channel.
@kosist: what code did you run to get all channels?

Comment: Please attach your tdms file, to reproduce the issue.

Comment: tdms file added, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. For me it works, I could access all 5 channels. Please post the code which gives this error trace. Because now code itself and stack trace are different (you don't call `channel = tdms_file["Untitled"]["Untitled 4"]` code, but this is the code which gives you the error).

Comment: That is very weird, I have no idea what I am missing.. other tdms files with one or two channels work just fine. Added the code and its outcome as an edit.

Comment: Okay well this is weird: just copied the tdms file onto my desktop and read it from there. Somehow it reads the 5 channels now. I have no idea what made this happen. Thank you @kosist for your help, greatly appreciate the effort!